# Map function does not execute after saving

Tags: javascript, mapreduce, couchdb

I am creating the below map function it chouchdb 1.3.0. If I run it as a temporary view it works fine, but as soon as I save it, it fails to compile.

```
function(doc) {
    var datestamp = convert_date(doc["report"]["period"]);
    var report_suite = doc["report"]["reportSuite"]["id"];
    var segment = doc["report"]["segment_id"];
    emit([report_suite, segment, datestamp], [doc["report"]["elements"][0]["id"]]);
  }

function convert_date(date){
    var months = {"Jan": "01", "Feb": "02", "Mar": "03", "Apr": "04", "May": "05",    "Jun": "06", "Jul": "07", "Aug": "08", "Sep": "09", "Oct": "10", "Nov": "11", "Dec": "12" };
    var year = date.substring(13, 17);
    var month = months[date.substring(8,11)];
    var day = date.substring(5,7).replace(" ", "0");
    var datestamp = year + month + day;
    return datestamp;
}
```

The error message is: "Expression does not eval to a function"

I have googled and tried unsuccessfully:

- Placing parentheses around the function
- inlining the convert_date function

Comment: How did you inline the convert_date() function? I think that should have worked.

Comment: just defined **var date = [what now in the function call]** it did not work either. More curiously All options worked after a code edit and pressing run, but not after saving the view and running again.

Comment: After you saved the view, did you try just sending a `GET` request to the view's URL directly?  That may trigger couch to rebuild the B-tree without needing to rely on Futon.  You don't need to wait for the request to complete, but if you look at the logs and/or `top` on the server you should see it re-building the tree.

Answer (score 2):

What if you place the convert_date function inside the map function?

```
  function(doc) {
    var convert_date = function(date) {
      var months = {"Jan": "01", "Feb": "02", "Mar": "03", "Apr": "04", "May": "05",    "Jun": "06", "Jul": "07", "Aug": "08", "Sep": "09", "Oct": "10", "Nov": "11", "Dec": "12" };
      var year = date.substring(13, 17);
      var month = months[date.substring(8,11)];
      var day = date.substring(5,7).replace(" ", "0");
      var datestamp = year + month + day;
      return datestamp;
    }
    var datestamp = convert_date(doc["report"]["period"]);
    var report_suite = doc["report"]["reportSuite"]["id"];
    var segment = doc["report"]["segment_id"];
    emit([report_suite, segment, datestamp], [doc["report"]["elements"][0]["id"]]);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is a weird one. I have now opened the actual design document, copied it and deleted all other functions and now it's working again.